# ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robot_localization/ekf_localization_node]

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, robot-localization, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. i am trying to work with robot_localization package. I get this error.

```
 ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robot_localization/ekf_localization_node]: can't locate node [ekf_localization_node] in package [robot_localization]
```

Update::
Apparently this worked for me...

First try,  `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`, then `roslaunch robot_localization ekf_template.launch`. If it work? If so, then need to `catkin clean` the workspace, `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`, `catkin build`  workspace, then workspace `cd devel` then `source setup.bash` file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333411/error:-cannot-launch-node-of-type-%5Brobot_localization/ekf_localization_node%5D/) by [enthusiast.australia](https://answers.ros.org/users/43404/enthusiast.australia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2019-09-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-09-20**:
just two things to check:

1. where does `roscd robot_localization` bring you?
2. do you have an unbuilt/unsuccesfully built `robot_localizaiton` package in the sourced workspace?

**Comment by [enthusiast.australia](https://answers.ros.org/users/43404/enthusiast.australia/) on 2019-09-20**:
roscd  takes me to the path

/opt/ros/kinetic/share/robot_localization/

How can i check whether i have successully built the package or not? When i run catkin cake, it does not show me robot_localization package with other packages. Did i incorrectly installed it?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-09-22**:
How did you install it?

**Comment by [enthusiast.australia](https://answers.ros.org/users/43404/enthusiast.australia/) on 2019-09-22**:
first i try to clone it, but it didn't work. after that i run [this command](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/tree/kinetic-devel)
`sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-robot-localization`
But still i have this error. Should i reinstall it? If yes, then can you help me how should i do tha?

WHen i tried to clone it, after everything, i did "catkin_make" and i get this error.

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by
"my_odom_configuration_dep" with any of the following names:

my_odom_configuration_depConfig.cmake
my_odom_configuration_dep-config.cmake

Invoking cmake failed.
```

What should i do ? i am not very experienced so may be i am missing something. Any help will be appreciated

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-09-23**:\

> roscd takes me to the path
> /opt/ros/kinetic/share/robot_localization/

If you are taken to this path, either your environment is not properly set up or you actually had an issue during installation. I guess it is the first, and not the second.
Please post the output of the following commands in the terminal where you get the `cannot launch...` error:

- `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`
- `find /opt/ros -name ekf_localization_node`

Then, try

```
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
rosrun robot_localization ekf_localization_node
```

If you don't get the same error as above, the installation is fine and there is a problem with your workspace. Try to remove any left-overs of the cloned `robot_localization` package (you should do that probably anyways) and see if it works after sourcing your workspace again.

The other error you get points to some problems in your workspace that are related to your packages (especially `my_odom_configuration_dep`). Please post the `CMakeLists.txt` for help

**Comment by [enthusiast.australia](https://answers.ros.org/users/43404/enthusiast.australia/) on 2019-09-23**:
when i run the find command, it gives me this error
find: ‘ekf_localization_node’: No such file or directory.

but if i run  "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash" and then "roslaunch ekf_template.launch", it runs for one time. I am confused whether i have installed it incorrectly or what.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-09-24**:
@enthusiast.australia there is definitively something wrong with your setup. Or with the `find` call. Please make sure you really copy the full command and also have the complete name, even missing one letter will result in no match, if you don't append any wildcards. If the launch file starts without problems, there cannot be an issue with the installed package.

To your original question: please try removing all left-overs from the cloned `robot_localization` repo, delete the `build` and `devel` folder in your workspace, and try to compile again.

**Comment by [enthusiast.australia](https://answers.ros.org/users/43404/enthusiast.australia/) on 2019-09-26**:
i have tried everything  but i am still having the original problem. when i try the above described way, i get this running without erroor.

```
shairi@ubuntu:/opt/ros/kinetic/share/robot_localization$ rosrun robot_localization ekf_localization_node 
[ INFO] [1569514546.025948593]: Waiting for valid clock time...
[ INFO] [1569514546.026111703]: Valid clock time received. Starting node.
```

So i get it that problem is with my workspace. I deleted my build and devel folders, then istalled the package again, but still having the same isssue.  i see something about deleting the workspace and creating new, but i am not sure ho to do that. Also if i do that, will my other packages and data be removed? OR what could be the alternative to use this package and clean my workspace?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-09-27**:\

> deleted my build and devel folders, then istalled the package again

What do you mean by that? Did you `apt-get install` the package `ros-kinetic-robot-localization` again? Or did you clone it from scratch?

Call `find <YOUR_WORKSPACE> -name robot_localization` and delete this package when you find it. Then remove the `build` and `devel` folder, recompile your workspace, `source` it again and check. Also, make sure that you haven't chained other workspaces.

If anything I say above is not clear, please exactly state what you don't understand and also what you have tried (i.e. the commands). Also post the relevant outputs.

Please do all that by **editing** your OP.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-09-30**:
@enthusiast.australia so is your question solved now? If yes, you can post this as an answer and accept that.

Actually, what you describe above is exactly what I was referring to with cleaning your workspace. I should have been more explicit about the single steps, probably...

You shouldn't have to do that again. So basically what you did was to newly set up your workspace chaining and recompile everything.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2019-11-18**:
Did you figure this issue out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the edited OP:

> Update: Apparently this worked for
> me...
>
> First try, source
> /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash, then
> roslaunch robot_localization
> ekf_template.launch. If it work? If
> so, then need to catkin clean the
> workspace, source
> /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash, catkin
> build workspace, then workspace cd
> devel then source setup.bash file.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2020-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0